# Web-Service retornando máxima cota excedida. Como resolver?

Tags: c#, json, web-service, rest, soap

Estou consumindo um web-service de terceiros. 
Quando recebo o retorno do serviço a seguinte mensagem é exibida:

> A cota máxima de tamanho de mensagens de entrada (65536) foi excedida

Já pesquisei em fóruns por uma solução, mas não obtive sucesso com nenhum...
Deixo abaixo meu app.config para verificação.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
            <messageLogging maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2147483647" />
        </diagnostics>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                        maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="URL DO WEB SERVICE"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12"
                contract="ServiceReference1.WorkflowWebServiceSoap" name="WorkflowWebServiceSoap12" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Alguém teria alguma proposta de solução?

Comment: Diminuir o tamanho da mensagem é uma solução.

Comment: Lembre-se que um serviço tem dois pontos, cliente e servidor. Precisa estar configurado para aceitar o tamanho da mensagem em ambos.

Comment: @RicardoPontual Obrigado, infelizmente não posso diminuir o tamanho da mensagem. Ricardo, preciso configurar algo do outro lado ? Ou seja, o web-service que estou consumindo deve ajustar isso do lado deles também ? Obrigado

Comment: Isso exatamente, é um Webservice escrito em .Net?

Answer (score 1):

Tive erro desse, porém o problema estava no lado client, e foi só alterar o `security mode` do `basicHttpBinding`:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WServicoSoapBinding">
        <security mode="Transport" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Também pode ser feito ao instanciar o objeto:

```
objWS = new NS.WServicoClient(new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport), new EndpointAddress(this.UrlWS));
```

Comment: O serviço é em HTTP e não HTTPS. Este security funcionaria da mesma maneira ?

Comment: acho que o `basicHttpBinding` é o mesmo para os dois. Inclusive esse ws que utilizo, é HTTPS também.